# Setup a Docker container with only the docker-compose up command

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, cakephp-3.0

I have an assessment in which I have to create a Docker container with CakePHP. I already have a working Docker container with CakePHP and I run the following commands for my container:

```
docker-compose build

docker-compose run cakephp composer install --no-interaction

docker-compose run cakephp bin/cake migrations migrate

docker-compose run cakephp bin/cake migrations seed

docker-compose up
```

The goal is to reduce the process down to only running the single command **docker-compose up** to be able to start testing the container. I'm very new to both Docker and CakePHP so I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Dockerfile**

```
#start with our base image (the foundation) - version 7.1.29
FROM php:7.1.29-apache

#install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \  
      gcc \
      make \
      autoconf \
      libc-dev \
      pkg-config \
      libicu-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      mysql-client \
      git \
      zip \
      unzip \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
      intl \
      mbstring \
      mcrypt \
      pcntl \
      pdo_mysql \
      pdo_pgsql \
      pgsql \
      opcache

RUN set -eux; apt-get update; apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev; docker-php-ext-install zip

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

#change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/webroot/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite && \
        echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

#copy source files and run composer
COPY . $APP_HOME

# install all PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction

#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  cakephp:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - "mysql"
    ports:
      - "4000:80"  
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      - SECURITY_SALT= *some salt here*  
      - MYSQL_URL=mysql
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:      
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cakephp
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

What I usually do to reduce my commands when handling Docker and Docker Compose in general is using a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)).

So, in your case, you could write something like:

**Makefile**

```
SUDO := $(shell groups | grep -q docker || echo sudo)

.PHONY: start

start:
    $(SUDO) docker-compose build \
    && $(SUDO) docker-compose run cakephp composer install --no-interaction \
    && $(SUDO) docker-compose run cakephp bin/cake migrations migrate \
    && $(SUDO) docker-compose run cakephp bin/cake migrations seed \
    && $(SUDO) docker-compose up
```

All you would have to do then is putting this file in your project folder and run `make start`.

(The `$(SUDO)` part ensures that you can run this comfortably even with a user that is not in the `docker` group.)

### Option 2

To really just run `docker-compose up` (perhaps with `--build` flag), you would have to write a little script that you `COPY` into the Docker image (you're already doing that with `COPY . $APP_HOME` – provided that you put this script at where your Docker build context points to) and then use it as `ENTRYPOINT`.

Something like this should work for you.

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

cakephp composer install --no-interaction
cakephp bin/cake migrations migrate
cakephp bin/cake migrations seed

exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, you would then have to put `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and thank you for taking the time to answer. The assessment itself asks for the completed container to only need the `docker-compose up` command to be able to test. I was reading online that possibly a shell script written within the Dockerfile could work, but I haven't had the time to try that yet.

Comment: @Logan, I've updated my answer, please check if you can go from there. :)

Comment: thank you for the help! It's greatly appreciated :)